# Special training and experience question on Russian Visa application

Tags: visas, russia

Question 28 on the Russian Visa application is:

> Special training and experience.
>   Do you have any specialized skills, training or experience related to firearms and explosives or to nuclear matters, biological or chemical substance?

I have a masters degree in biology and worked in a lab for 8 years. I don't know anything special for a biologist. I guess I'm looking for some guidance in answering this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NBC question refers to nuclear, biological and chemical *warfare*. If you have some specialized knowledge regarding such topics, then that is what you would want to answer about here. For instance, if you worked with such weapons in the military.

Interestingly, the US visa application DS-160 has a virtually identical question.

Comment: I also read it that way but it's not clear from the sentence structure.

Comment: There is no reason for any state to care about every biologist. But if you worked with things like anthrax or Agent Orange then they surely want to know.